# Is there a guaranteed order of queries in a single MySql session?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a single MySql session, say that Query A performs a read of the table and Query B performs a write on the table that would affect what Query A would return.

If I submit Query A followed (perhaps a few ms later) by Query B, is the result deterministic? Is it possible for Query B to complete before Query A?

Or if the order is instead [Query B, Query A], is there a guarantee that the result from Query A will contain the changes done in Query B?

Comment: How could A complete after B? The application only starts B after A is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a *single* session, then be aware that MySQL does not support multiple concurrent queries.  You have to finish read query A before executing query B.

Some client interfaces make it seem like you can still fetch results from query A, even though you have moved on to execute query B.  But this is possible because the client library has already fetched all the results from query A into application memory, and what you see in your code as subsequent fetches are really just iterating over the result in memory.

If you're talking about *multiple* concurrent sessions, then @Ian Atkin's answer comes into play.  The storage engine and the transaction isolation level can affect the result.

Comment: Yeah, this is a single persistent session used by a NodeJS server.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is in some ways determined by the table type being employed, and whether the queries are in the same thread or coming from multiple sessions. For a complete discussion of this you should consult the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html), specifically on the subject of "locking".

If these queries are being performed by the same script there probably won't be a problem. Query B would not affect the results from Query A, etc.

From the docs...

> MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY and MERGE tables,
>   page-level locking for BDB tables, and row-level locking for InnoDB
>   tables.
>
> In many cases, you can make an educated guess about which locking type
>   is best for an application, but generally it is difficult to say that
>   a given lock type is better than another. Everything depends on the
>   application and different parts of an application may require
>   different lock types.
>
> To decide whether you want to use a storage engine with row-level
>   locking, you should look at what your application does and what mix of
>   select and update statements it uses. For example, most Web
>   applications perform many selects, relatively few deletes, updates
>   based mainly on key values, and inserts into a few specific tables.
>   The base MySQL MyISAM setup is very well tuned for this.
>
> Table locking in MySQL is deadlock-free for storage engines that use
>   table-level locking. Deadlock avoidance is managed by always
>   requesting all needed locks at once at the beginning of a query and
>   always locking the tables in the same order.

Comment: And for InnoDB tables, it will also depend on the [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read)